# tempname() not creating directory

Tags: vim

I've encountered an issue with a Vim plugin where it attempts to get a temporary file but it fails to create the directory.

So when it gets used, the plugin fails because the directory was never created, hence it throws an error since the file was never written to.

I have been only able to reproduce on Gentoo:

```
:let temp_file = tempname()
:echo temp_file
/tmp/vhISQyY/3
Press ENTER or type command to continue
:!ls /tmp/
pathogen  pip_build_vagrant  solarized

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The plugin follows the same example given in `:help tempname()` which is to redirect a command.

I understand that the file will not exist, but not having a directory breaks. Other plugins that use `tempname()` never check for the existence of the containing directory and just write to it so I wonder if this is a Vim bug or if I am really doing something wrong in the plugin.

This is an excerpt from tpope's `fugitive` plugin that uses `tempname()` in the same way (without checking a directory):

```
let errorfile = tempname()
try
  try
    execute cd.s:fnameescape(s:repo().tree())
    if &shell =~# 'cmd'
      let command = ''
      let old_editor = $GIT_EDITOR
      let $GIT_EDITOR = 'false'
    else
      let command = 'env GIT_EDITOR=false '
    endif
    let command .= s:repo().git_command('commit').' '.a:args
    if &shell =~# 'csh'
      noautocmd silent execute '!('.command.' > '.outfile.') >& '.errorfile
    elseif a:args =~# '\%(^\| \)--interactive\>'
      noautocmd execute '!'.command.' 2> '.errorfile
    else
      noautocmd silent execute '!'.command.' > '.outfile.' 2> '.errorfile
    endif
  finally
    execute cd.'`=dir`'
  endtry
  ...
```

And the plugin that fails is using it like this:

```
let tmp_path = tempname()
silent! execute "keepalt w " . tmp_path
```

Comment: Pretty sure that "/tmp" existing is a POSIX requirement.  It's hard-coded in stdio.h.  So it never needs to be created.

Comment: @stark it is not `/tmp/` that is missing, I'm listing that directory (`/tmp/`) to demonstrate that the directory Vim said it existed does not: `vhISQyY` in my example.

Answer (score 4):

Something is deleting or cleaning up your /tmp directory. I have once proposed a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/cogp-Vye4oo/d_SVFXBbnnoJ), to fix this issue, but Bram didn't want to include it. Since then, I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
"In case /tmp get's clean out, make a new tmp directory for vim:               
:command! Mktmpdir call mkdir(fnamemodify(tempname(),":p:h"),"",0700)
```

Comment: This is really odd, I get: `E739: Cannot create directory: /tmp/vXlIB4W` But if I `ls /tmp/` it is there. It gets removed when I quite Vim.

Comment: If the temp directory exists, then Vim shouldn't have a problem accessing the tempfiles and your plugin should work as well.